# File not found Exception by reading a JSON File

Tags: android, json, filenotfoundexception

I wrote some code to read a JSON File from SD Card.

For the first I save the Path for my appfolder.

```
Boolean isMounted = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if (isMounted) {
        File Dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyIdea");
        //creat folder if don't exist
        if (!Dir.exists()) {
            if (!Dir.mkdir()) {
                Log.d("MyIdea", "failed to create");
            }
        }
        //set the absolutPath to appPathString
        appDataPath = Dir.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

After that I put the config.json into the folder and want to read the JSON File from SD-Card with this method.

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open(appDataPath + "/config.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

After that i want to get Data from the File

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
```

But if I run the code through the Debugger I get the message on ex:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyIdea/config.json
```

Comment: did you check config.json file is in MyIdea or not?

Comment: Yes, i checked it on my Device. 

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161102/vkcdfgtc.png

Comment: Do you have read/write permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is not in your `assets` folder but still you are using `getAssets`. The file in the sdcard can be opened just like any normal file in java.

Try this,

```
public String loadJSON() {
    String json = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(appDataPath + "/config.json"));
        String line;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        json = buffer.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Also make sure you have the following permission in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Do not create a buffer with size same as your file size. If the file is a large file, there is a high chance that you will run into an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Works great. Save my day. Thanks a lot!